# Translate tikz arrow tips to pstricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have a document which contains tikz pictures and pstricks pictures which both contain lots of arrows. Usually I use tikz to do my own stuff but I got the pstricks pictures from another source and want just to include them. The problem is that I want that the arrows from both pictures look identical.

To make the question a bit more general: For which of the following tikz-arrow-tips is a pstricks equivalent which looks identical and how to typeset it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tarrow}[1]{#1 & \tikz[>=#1] \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
   standard tikz & \tikz \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);\\
   \tarrow{latex}\\
   \tarrow{latex'}\\
   \tarrow{stealth} \\
   \tarrow{stealth'} \\
   \tarrow{triangle 90} \\
   \tarrow{triangle 60} \\
   \tarrow{triangle 45} \\
   \tarrow{open triangle 90} \\
   \tarrow{open triangle 60} \\
   \tarrow{open triangle 45} \\
   \tarrow{angle 90} \\
   \tarrow{angle 60} \\
   \tarrow{angle 45} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Not that I could be helpful either way, but would you be open to recreating the pstricks arrows in tikz? Since you already have greater familiarity with tikz, you might find such a solution easier to understand and implement.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Yes that would also be possible, but I would prefer the way from tikz to pstricks since I usually work with tikz and want the pstricks pictures behave this way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to `tikZ` but I've been using `pstricks` for quite a while.  You can create all of these arrows in `pstricks`.  The problem is you need to create some of them yourself (from scratch).  `pstricks` has a very limited preset library of arrows.  There are parameters to adjust the shape of an arrow: `arrowsize`, `arrowlength`, and `arrowinset`.  The overall size of the arrow can be changed by using `arrowscale`.  By adjusting these values you can get almost all of the arrows except for the first and the last three.  I'm not sure whether there's an adjustment for the open triangles.

If you look at the `pstricks` manual and search for **arrowheads** you get a very good idea of what to do to get the desired effects.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
 texdoc pst-arrow
```

then you'll get all possible arrows.