# Change the style of arrows in all possible ways

Tags: tikz-arrows

Question: In my below `MWE`, i just want to change the style of arrows (in all possible ways) on every lines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    \LARGE
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (0,0)-- (0,4);
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (0,0)-- (4,0);
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (0,4)-- (4,4);
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (4,0)-- (10,0);
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (10,0)-- (10,4);
\draw [line width=0.3pt] (10,4)-- (7,2);
\begin{scope}[very thick,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}
] 
\draw [line width=0.3pt,postaction={decorate}] (0,0)-- (0,4);
%\draw [line width=1pt,postaction={decorate}] (0,0)-- (4,4);(this command create arrow with line segment)
\draw [line width=0.3pt,postaction={decorate}] (4,4)-- (0,4);
\draw [line width=0.3pt,postaction={decorate}] (4,0)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=0.3pt,postaction={decorate}] (4,0)-- (10,0);
\draw [line width=0.3pt,postaction={decorate}] (10,0)-- (10,4);
\draw [line width=0.3pt,postaction={decorate}] (7,2)-- (10,4);
\end{scope}
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.0437,-0.42) node {$V_2$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.0437,4.4) node {$V_1$};
\draw [fill=black] (4,0) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.97592,-0.42) node {$V_3$};
\draw [fill=black] (4,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.97592,4.4) node {$V_4$};
\draw [fill=black] (10,0) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.96542,-0.42) node {$V_5$};
\draw [fill=black] (10,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.96542,4.42) node {$V_6$};
\draw [fill=black] (7,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (6.93074,1.60589) node {$V_7$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be this helps to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/translate-tikz-arrow-tips-to-pstricks

Comment: @MadyYuvi Would you please illustrate by giving an example?

Comment: What necessary changes that i have to make in my MWE?

Comment: I understand that you want to change the arrow style, if my assumption is correct, in the provided link, the OP showed many arrow styles, so only I suggested that. Is anything wrong in this? Please advise....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Nothing wrong. I accepted your suggestion but the problem is i dont have good command in latex drawing in fact in tikz that is why i am telling you that do some correction in above codes.

Comment: Help me in this question.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood, you would like to change the style of your arrows altogether.

You can define a style (for example, `myar`), then if you change the style, you'll change all the arrows at once.

I have also simplified your code using a TikZ matrix.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    myar/.style={
        line cap=round,
        line join=round,
        >=triangle 45,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
            },
        postaction={decorate},
        line width=.5pt,
        },
    myline/.style={
        line width=.5
        pt,
        }
    }

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=1.63cm,
    column sep=2.6cm,
    nodes={draw, circle, fill=black, minimum width=5pt,inner sep=0pt, font=\scriptsize}
    ] (mymatr) {
    |[label=$V_1$]| &[1cm] |[label=$V_4$]| && |[label=$V_6$]| \\
    && |[label=below:$V_7$]| \\
    |[label=below:$V_2$]| & |[label=below:$V_3$]| && |[label=below:$V_5$]| \\
    };
\draw [myar] (mymatr-1-2) -- (mymatr-1-1);
\draw [myar] (mymatr-3-1) -- (mymatr-1-1);
\draw [myar] (mymatr-3-2) -- (mymatr-3-1);
\draw [myar] (mymatr-3-2) -- (mymatr-3-4);
\draw [myar] (mymatr-3-4) -- (mymatr-1-4);
\draw [myar] (mymatr-2-3) -- (mymatr-1-4);
\draw [myline] (mymatr-3-2) -- (mymatr-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]